# Converting an XML ElementTree as String to XML String

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need to convert an XML ElementTree - that I already have as a String - to a proper XML content String. I'm not sure if my ElementTree is properly formatted, which might be why I am getting unexpected results.

I tried the using following code:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = '_XML_Worksheet(_XML_Group("view" = "presentation","hide-input" = "false","hide-output" = "false","inline-output" = "false","drawlabel" = "true",`_XML_Text-field`("alignment" = "centred","style" = "Text","layout" = "Normal","ok")))'

root = ET.Element(tree)

xml = ET.tostring(root)

print(xml.decode())
```

But this code gave me some gibberish:

```
<_XML_Worksheet(_XML_Group("view" = "presentation","hide-input" = "false","hide-output" = "false","inline-output" = "false","drawlabel" = "true",`_XML_Text-field`("alignment" = "centred","style" = "Text","layout" = "Normal","ok"))) />
```

When this is what i expected:

```xml
<Worksheet><Group view='presentation' hide-input='false' hide-output='false' inline-output='false' drawlabel='true'><Text-field alignment='centred' style='Text' layout='Normal'>ok</Text-field></Group></Worksheet>
```